# udev: Wrong symlink is made at boot time

Tags: linux, usb, udev, ttyusb

I am trying to create a udev rule to give a static name to a ttyUSB (a FTDI USB serial cable).

My rule is quite simple (the file is named 99-usb-serial.rules):

> KERNEL=="ttyUSB?",
>   ATTRS{serial}=="FTYK0GQY",
>   MODE="0666",
>   SYMLINK+="ttySOV"

The rule works fine when I hot plug the USB cable into the computer. However, it does not work when I boot while the USB cable is plugged in. Instead of creating a symlink to ttyUSB0 (or any number), I get a symlink on sda2. On another machine I get a symlink on vcs8.

Does anyone know what is going on there? It seems like Google is letting me down on this one.

udev version is 204 and Linux kernel version is 3.13.0.

Thanks a lot!